# "Apache are" or "Apache is"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is more correct when I'm talking about Apache 2 (HTTP webserver)?

> It is Apache

or

> They are Apache

I think it's "Apaches are". What's correct?

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: Apache is/are being used to ping-pong HTTP requests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what type of Apache you mean.

For the computer science term it would be:

```
 "Apache is being used to ping-pong HTTP requests."
```

For the group of native Americans it would be:

```
 "The Apache are a tribe of native Americans."
```

Answer (score 4):

When talking about the HTTP webserver, it is correct to use:

> It is Apache2/Apache2 is being used to ping-pong HTTP requests

The way you say:

> It is Microsoft

Comment: "Apache" should be capitalized as it is a proper name.

Comment: It's "apache2" as stated in linux's "top" command)

Comment: @genesis: "apache2" is the name of the executable (that "top" outputs, for instance "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start"), not how you refer to the webserver (unless it is specifically about the executable). You refer to the web server as "Apache" or "Apache 2.0" (shorthand for the full name "Apache HTTP Server" or "Apache HTTP Server 2.0")

Comment: @rintaun: don't you mean proper noun (instead of proper name)?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I suppose that is what I meant. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The name derives from the self-deprecating description "a patchy webserver", so it seems the developers considered it to be **singular**.

The software is called *apache* or, for version 2, *apache2* in line with the Unix practice of using only lower-case in the name of executable files.

The webserver is one of the projects under the umbrella of the *Apache Software Foundation* which lists the projects with the capitalisation befitting proper nouns (as well it might).

The situation is analogous to *Perl*, the programming language. **Perl** is the name of the language, but the program on my computer disk is **perl**.

---

EDIT: It thought I'd made it clear what I was saying, but to make it hopefully more clear:

The project is called **Apache**, the executable file is called `apache`, or `apache2`. I'm sure the Question is about the *project*, not the *file*, and it's clearly **singular**.

Comment: No, it is "Apache", not "apache". And the executable is often named "httpd" (for example, */usr/local/apache/bin/httpd*). See for instance *[Using Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html)*.

Comment: I'm actually *agreeing* with you @Peter, the webserver project is called 'Apache' by its creators, but the software [the `daemon`] is called `apache` or `apache2`. I wouldn't expect questions about `httpd`, the version I use now is called `apache2`